# If I have multiple 'click' events added onto a single DOM object, are they always going to fire based on the way they were added?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

If i add multiple click events onto a single DOM object lets say

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){

})

document.addEventListener('click2', function(e){

})
```

are they always going to fire base on when they are added? first 'click' then 'click2' ?

Comment: There is no formal spec around this, so even if they do in every browser you test in, don't _rely_ on them firing in order. If you need sequential event handling, bind a single click handler, and then delegate each thing that needs to happen on click inside that handler, instead of binding multiple handlers.

Comment: you can also use event bubbling to make sure the ‘deepest’ event handler gets called first. For example, you can listen for clicks on a button, and on the div containing that button.

Comment: hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can u give an example please

Comment: Just... what I said? Instead of two `addEventListener` bindings, just add a single one, and make the handling function call the two functions you need called, in sequence. `addEventListener("click", evt => { doFirstThing(evt); doSecondThing(evt); })`.

Comment: Normally the "DOMEvents" are synchronous. But there's no official evidence for what you're saying. It is likely that different results in different devices will emerge or behave inconsistently. Moreover, a code written in this way will give you an extra load. At this point, checking the events and calling two separate functions within a single event listener will require you to perform both synchronous and less logical queries.